# JTextpane lost focus when double-struck input

Tags: java

I insert a jtextarea into a jtextpane.
When input in jtextarea, the focus always go into the outter textpanel.
It only occur when there is double-struck in the textpane.

It's ok if there is no double-struck charactor.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

JTextPane jTextPane = new JTextPane();
jTextPane.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", 0, 12));

JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

jTextPane.getDocument().insertString(jTextPane.getDocument().getLength(), "a", null);
jTextPane.getDocument().insertString(jTextPane.getDocument().getLength(), "\uD835\uDD38", null);
jTextPane.getDocument().insertString(jTextPane.getDocument().getLength(), "b", null);

jTextPane.insertComponent(area);
frame.add(jTextPane);
frame.setSize(100, 100);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I want to continuous input text in the textarea.

Comment: I google it, and it seems to be a bug of jdk. It's OK in jdk12, but not work it jdk8

Comment: How to close this question?